# How to include a php and then remove it?

Tags: php, file, plugins, include

Well, I don't know if this post have the correct title. Feel free to change it.

Ok, this is my scenario:

**pluginA.php**

```
function info(){
   return "Plugin A";
}
```

**pluginB.php**

```
function info(){
   return "Plugin B";
}
```

Finally, I have a plugin manager that is in charge of import all plugins info to pool array:
**Manager.php**

```
class Manager
{
    protected $pool;

    public function loadPluginsInfo()
    {
        $plugin_names = array("pluginA.php", "pluginB.php");

        foreach ($plugin_names as $name) 
        {
            include_once $name;
            $this->pool[] = info(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when I print pool array it only show me the info on the first plugin loaded. I supposed that the file inclusing override the info because it still calling the info() method from the first include.

Is there a way to include the info  of both plugins having the info() function with the same name for all plugins files?

Thank you in advance

PS: a fatal cannot redeclare error is never hurled

Comment: why you don't  create in pluginA.php the Class `PluginA`? so you can acces to the info method `PluginA::Info();` (that's OOP)

Comment: I had that option, but I don't know how to instanciate a class dynamically by that way, because I only can get the plugin file name

Comment: You'd be trying to redefine the `info()` function, which PHP doesn't allow. so only the FIRST instance of `info()` will get defined (plugin A), and the rest will get ignored.

Comment: Usually, this should throw a fatal cannot redeclare error. You can use David's suggestion in the same way as your code is, just replace $this->pool[] = info();  with $tmp = new $name(); $this->pool[] = $tmp->info();

Comment: @32bitfloat is right! you cannot define the same method twice - it will not compile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the dynamic way to create plugin classes

plugin class

```
class PluginA
{
    public function info()
    {
        return 'info'; //the plugin info
    }
}
```

manager class

```
class Manager
{
    protected $pool;

    public function loadPluginsInfo()
    {
        $plugin_names = array("pluginA", "pluginB"); //Plugin names

        foreach ($plugin_names as $name) 
        {
            $file = $name . '.php';
            if(file_exists($file))
            {
                require_once($file); //please use require_once
                $class = new $name(/* parameters ... */); //create new plugin object

                //now you can call the info method like: $class->info();
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No more adding to the pool though?

Comment: if you want to do that, you can do it ;)

Comment: Thank you @David, Nice solution!   ...and the rest of people thank you so much too!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the interpreter isn't choking w/ a fatal error?  It should be since you're trying to define the `info` function twice here.

There are many ways to achieve what you want, one way as in @David's comment above would be to use classes, eg.

```
class PluginA
{
  function info() { return 'Plugin A'; }
}

class PluginB
{
  function info() { return 'Plugin B'; }
}
```

then the Manager class would be something like this:

```
class Manager
{
    protected $pool;

    public function loadPluginsInfo()
    {
        $plugin_names = array("PluginA", "PluginB");

        foreach ($plugin_names as $name) 
        {
            include_once $name . '.php';
            $this->pool[] = new $name();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have an instance of each plugin class loaded, so to get the info for a plugin you would have `$this->pool[0]->info();` for the first plugin.  I would recommend going w/ an associative array though so you can easily reference a given plugin.  To do this, the assignment to the pool would become:

```
$this->pool[$name] = new name();
```

And then you can say:

```
$this->pool['PluginA']->info();
```

for example.

There are many other ways to do it.  Now that 5.3 is mainstream you could just as easily [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) your groups of functions, but I would still recommend the associative array for the pool as you can reference a plugin in constant time, rather than linear.

Comment: You should first check whether the file is in place to avoid runtime errors

Comment: Yes, this is true; a combination of your and my answer FTW!