# how to include a PHP page and then remove it completely?

Tags: javascript, php, include

I want to include a PHP file which is for Loading JavaScript and then remove it completely from page. I found same article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460940/how-to-include-a-php-and-then-remove-it) but I don't know how to use it.

Let's see I included PHP like this in top of page.

```
<?php include 'loader.php';?>
```

So, how to remove it when page loaded completely?

loader.php is already working singly, I mean after few seconds will be removed loading content, but it doesn't work when I include it to other page. so how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: you can't "uninclude" a file. and php can't retroactively delete html that's already been sent to the client. if you want to remove whatever html that loader produced, you'll need to use client-side JS.

Comment: Why do you need to remove it once the page has loaded? Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: As I mentioned, loader.php is loading script page, after few seconds will be removed automatically, but when I include it to the page then it doesn't work. however the loader.php is working singly. so, of course it's because of js conflicts in the page. I'm looking for a method that include a single PHP file and then when it's loaded,  it will be removed too from  entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Put your content **into div**

```
<div class="js-remove-this"> <?php include 'loader.php';?> </div>
```

Then listen with JS for page onload event and remove **div.js-remove-this**